# How can you detect the connection and disconnection of external monitors on the Mac?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Do you have any idea how I can detect additional screens being plugged in / unplugged in a Cocoa application?

I want to detect the moment when the user plugs or unplugs another screen to his Mac. How could I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Your answer lies in Quartz.

```
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

CGError CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback (
    CGDisplayReconfigurationCallBack proc,
    void *userInfo
);
```

And then your proc looks like:

```
 MyCGDisplayReconfigurationCallBack(
    CGDirectDisplayID display,
    CGDisplayChangeSummaryFlags flags,
    void *userInfo) {
    
    if (flags & kCGDisplayAddFlag || flags & kCGDisplayRemoveFlag) {
        DoStuff(display, flags, userInfo);
    }
}
```

In Swift5:

```
extension ScreenDetector {

    static let callback: CGDisplayReconfigurationCallBack = { (displayId, flags, userInfo) in
        guard let opaque = userInfo else {
            return
        }
        let mySelf = Unmanaged<ScreenDetector>.fromOpaque(opaque).takeUnretainedValue()
        
        if flags.contains(.addFlag) {
            //Add Display...
        }else if flags.contains(.removeFlag) {
            //Removed Display...
        }
        
    }

    func addObervers() {
        let userData = Unmanaged<ScreenDetector>.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()
        CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback(ScreenDetector.callback, userData)
    }
    
    func removeObservers() {
        let userData = Unmanaged<ScreenDetector>.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()
        CGDisplayRemoveReconfigurationCallback(ScreenDetector.callback, userData)
    }
}
```

Comment: The check may be optimized to the easier-to-read `flags & (kCGDisplayAddFlag | kCGDisplayRemoveFlag)`.

Comment: Or you could use the higher-level notification: `NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification`

Comment: @Mark Cao, I am getting an error trying to use your Swift 5 solution "Cannot find type 'ScreenDetector' in scope."  Did you create another class for this that isn't shown in your edit?

Comment: @SouthernYankee65 Yes, but it's a base class to call the methods in extension.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested in doing this in Swift 2.3, I scratched my head for a little while to translate @iluvcapra 's code:

```
let userData = UnsafeMutablePointer<ViewController>(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()) //use the class name of your "self" for future reference inside the callback
CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback({ (display: UInt32, flags: CGDisplayChangeSummaryFlags, userInfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Void>) in
    let mySelf = Unmanaged<ViewController>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(userInfo)).takeUnretainedValue() //change here to your class name
    if flags.rawValue & CGDisplayChangeSummaryFlags.AddFlag.rawValue > 0 {
        //do stuff on connect
        mySelf.someFunction()
    } else if flags.rawValue & CGDisplayChangeSummaryFlags.RemoveFlag.rawValue > 0 {
        //do stuff on disconnect
    }
}, userData)
```